# Handle NullObjects

Tags: null

I have done quite a bit of research on best ways to deal with null objects.
The best I came across so far is using the Ternary Operator.

```
String x = object.getString1!=null?object.getString1:"";
```

However I am not really satisfied with this since it still means constantly checking for null.
The other thing I have read about was not having getter methods that return null but returning a "Null Object" instance. 
However I do not see how I could get this to work for Integers/BigDecimal/etc... since they by default hold a value.

I am not 100% keen on the idea of implementing NullObjects either. Has anyone else got a better idea of how to go about handling null's?

Comment: Since 'Integers/BigDecimal/etc' already have a value they clearly aren't part of the problem. Wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 1):

If your approach works well for you, why not refactor it to a static method and use all the time?

[Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has done something similar for strings. If you take a look under the hood of [Strings](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/base/Strings.java) class, you can see the `nullToEmpty` method which is implemented like this:

```
public static String nullToEmpty(@Nullable String string) {
    return (string == null) ? "" : string;
 }
```

Don't concern yourself with the `@Nullable` annotation.

But from your code, I suspect there are bigger problems lurking around. Null Integers and BigDecimal are a sign that something, somewhere isn't really right, and you might want to check the relevent parts. Having these objects set somewhere to null could be an indicator that you should be throwing an exception, but that decision is up to you, of course.

Comment: Well the null Integers and BigDecimals are intended. Since most of the data is populated out of a DB and the fields are nullable you wouldn't want an Integer with value 0 - you would want to no that there is no data in that field i.e. null still that leaves the issue of developers forgetting to check for null when they don't expect it.

Comment: If those BigDecimals are null in your relational model, it suggests they are non-mandatory so rather than return magic numbers to indicate those values are optional maybe use an Optional<BigDecimal> to indicate the value may or may not exist. Guava library has an Optional implementation and it will be part of the core API for Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using C#, you could use the `operator ??`:

```
String x = object.getString1 ?? "";
```

which is, IMHO, more readable.

As for your question, I can't see where's the point in using Null Object pattern for value type, as you already noted they can't hold a null value unless they are declared as Nullable so you will always have a *valid* value (valid in the language domain but maybe not valid in the application domain). So, this is a whole different question.

What you have to do with a null pointer really depends on the context, maybe a Null Object is suitable, but if it's not feasibile you should throw an exception or maybe use some default...